# Difference between difference Type.DEFAULT and Type.STACKED in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

Hello i start using achartengine , after the creation of a barchart , i noticed that the width of the bar can't be modified within you define your barchart view as Type.STACKED i.e

```
 GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset,multiRenderer, Type.STACKED);
```

So what is the difference between `Type.DEFAULT` and `Type.STACKED`? and why the width can be just modified in Type.DEFAULT?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, official [doc](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/chart/BarChart.Type.html) does not explain that, but you always can learn [usage](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/chart/class-use/BarChart.Type.html) of it at project (it is open source) OR ask [creator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391554/dan) about it.